# How to Align menu in navigation bar to right side using Bootstrap ml-auto?

Tags: bootstrap-4, grid, margin-left

I'm trying to align the menu's in bootstrap navigation bar using ml-auto, But it is not working. Instead of that we can align the menu's using margin-left:auto in style tag. **Why is bootstrap ml-auto is not working?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **Bootstrap 5**,

```
s - (start) for classes that set margin-left 
or padding-left in LTR, margin-right or padding-right 
in RTL
```

so, try using `ms-auto`
More info
[here.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/#notation)